# Changing system properties in Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, session-cookies

I have found lots of links saying that if I want to change the name of my session cookie all I have to do is modify the following system properties.

```
org.apache.catalina.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME
org.apache.catalina.SESSION_PARAMETER_NAME
```

How do I do this? I looked inside Catalina.properties but I'm not sure. Is there a way of modifying these properties through Context.xml,server.xml, or web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually set system properties in `setenv.sh` in the `bin` folder of the instance.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dsysprop.name=sysprop.value"
```

Do note, however, that the default values for the properties you mention are defined in the servlet specification, so changing them might have implications.